# Union types in interface: Property '_seconds' does not exist on type 'Date'

Tags: typescript

I have two interfaces:

```js
interface Timestamp {
  _seconds: number;
  _nanoseconds: number;
}

interface Item {
  createdAt: Timestamp | Date;
}
```

But after compile I got an error:

```js
Property '_seconds' does not exist on type 'Timestamp | Date'.
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the code that accesses `_seconds`? I'd guess you're accessing `createdAt._seconds`, which won't work if you've assigned a Date to `createdAt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access `_seconds` on `item.createdAt`, however since this is an **Union type**, TS doesn't know if its value is, at runtime, a `Timestamp` or a `Date`, so it is warning you that, if it's a `Date`, `_seconds` would be undefined.

You can use `in` operator to check if property is present, in this case TS will narrow `createdAt` type to `Timestamp`, and now you can access `_seconds` without errors from the compiler:

```
if ('_seconds' in item!.createdAt) {
    item!.createdAt._seconds;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=13&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCrALYQM5jhgB2QG8AoZZAfWwgQHsQATbALmRAFcMAjaAbnJUQcEHRr0mrdl15QBAX1KlQkWIhQBJSBhKCEUCHEiMAgmDbosufEQA+yACJGICpQBsIYZMG1stEDAEfAIBCADp9Q2MzMOpaBmYBZRhkAAoAcjiJZnTvEG9tcMjnUzAASl0KCmCMIoMSmKyE7AUgA)

Comment: Thank you, you are absolutely right and your answer works for me.